# Integrating touch screen in a multi-screen setup

Tags: touchscreen

I am running a multi-screen workstation (seven Dell 24" screens).

I would like to change one of my screens to be a touch screen and use it as my main desktop in the configuration.

1. Is this possible?
2. Can I use the normal mouse on the touch screen?

The system is running Windows 7 64-bit with three NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560TI cards.

Comment: I'm also concerned about this. How does the mouse factor in with touch? Do you still see the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know about a 7 screens workstation, but with a two screens configuration or with a laptop with a touchscreen and one or two additional non-touch screens, there is no problem at all
2. Of course